# Who keeps the second set of sneakers?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, shlichus-agency

If I appoint an agent to go purchase a pair of sneakers for me and, upon arriving at the store the agent notices they are having a two-for-one sale (which I was not aware of), when the agent buys the shoes can the agent keep the second pair for himself?

Comment: Why would he,if the second pair is free only because the sender paid fir the first

Answer (score 4):

See Masheches Kesuvos 98b Rav Papa brings the halacha if the price is fixed they share the extra and if it is not fixed the sender keeps it see it inside.Here is a good story and source for such a case,it seems this case is that belongs fully to the sender because the extra one comes because of the first pair ,it is like part of the sale,and that is how it is initially advertised.

http://www.businesshalacha.com/articles/chanukah-extra